# Conveying 'kill it' (i.e. do sth extremely well)

Tags: traduction, anglais, langage-informel

'Kill it' (informal) to do something extremely well:

> Chris kills it on drums.
>
> Paul Stanley (KISS) has praised PANTERA's comeback, saying the band's
> new lineup is "killin' it".

Google's and Deepl's translation is by 'le tue' but it sounds but a literal translation.

> Chris le tue à la batterie.
> Paul Stanley (KISS) a fait l'éloge du retour de PANTERA, affirmant que la nouvelle formation du groupe "le tue".

So how can one convey this meaning of 'kill it'?

Comment: You should look up *être une tuerie* and *faire un massacre*, although neither precisely match *to kill it*. *Ça tue*, *il tue*, *elle tue* (no object complement) also exist in this ballpark, but once again there are differences in usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour garder la métaphore et le registre familier, je dirais :

> Chris tue tout à la batterie

> Chris à la batterie, c'est une tuerie

> Chris est un tueur à la batterie

> La nouvelle composition du groupe est une tuerie

Answer (score 1):

« Le tue » ne va pas du tout, du moins pour l'instant, les idées de « making a killing » et expression similaires n'étant pas du tout propre au français.

La traduction est sujette au contexte.

Dans des circonstances qui sont celles du travail on peut utiliser des expressions comme les suivantes.

- faire un travail sensationnel/exceptionnel/remarquable/hors pair/formidable

S'il s'agit d'activité artistique, quelque chose d'autre est préférable.

- donner une/des performances hors pairs/sensationnelle/exceptionnelle/remarquable

S'il s'agit d'un sportif « hors pair » est toujours utilisable.

- fournir un effort hors ligne/hors pair/sensationnelle/exceptionnelle/remarquable

> Chris donne des performance hors pair à la batterie. Paul Stanley (KISS) a fait l'éloge du retour de PANTERA, affirmant que la nouvelle formation du groupe *dépasse tout ce que l'on aurait pu en attendre*.

Il y a des termes informels, que l'on peut même appeler argotiques, comme « sensas » et « formid » (vieilli), mais un amateur de musique classique ne les utilise pas en parlant des interprètes dont il commente les performances.

> Chris est sensas à la batterie. Paul Stanley (KISS) a fait l'éloge du retour de PANTERA, affirmant que la nouvelle formation du groupe *est formid*.

*familier ou argot, pas élégant* : à tout casser (TLFi), casser la barraque

> Chris casse la barraque à la batterie. Paul Stanley (KISS) a fait l'éloge du retour de PANTERA, affirmant que la nouvelle formation du groupe *donne des performances à tout casser*.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse super !